# Can't build Qt on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

I have just installed `Qt Creator 3.2.2` on `OSX 10.9.5`, put line `QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9` into .pro file and changed the line `QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.8` into `QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9` inside `device.pri` file. Now I'm trying to compile a very simple project. And it doesn't compile. It gives me the following output:

```
23:11:21: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" clean
rm -f main.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
23:11:21: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
23:11:21: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
23:11:21: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -g   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mFile Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Applications/Xcode Invalid Arguments  -version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../Test -I/Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I. -F/Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/lib -o main.o ../Test/main.cpp
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [main.o] Error 2
23:11:22: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
23:11:22: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

What's wrong here? How do I fix it?

EDIT. A part of Makefile:

> MAKEFILE      = Makefile

```
####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
CXX           = /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
DEFINES       = -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mFile Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Applications/Xcode Invalid Arguments  -version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mFile Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Applications/Xcode Invalid Arguments  -version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../Test -I/Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I. -F/Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/lib
LINK          = /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
LFLAGS        = -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -mFile Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Applications/Xcode Invalid Arguments  -version-min=10.6
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -F/Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/lib -framework QtCore 
AR            = /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar cq
RANLIB        = /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib -s
QMAKE         = /Applications/QT/5.3/clang_64/bin/qmake
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
STRIP         = 
INSTALL_FILE  = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
```

Comment: Do you have SDK 10.9 installed?

Comment: @N1ghtLight yes, Xcode 6 uses it

Comment: Looks like the space in the path to the MacOSX sdk may be the issue. Try placing it in some place without spaces in path, changing it's path in .bash_profile and run qmake and make again. If that doesn't help, providing the Makefile, generated by qmake may help solving the problem.

Comment: @VVV how do I find that Makefile?

Comment: It should be in the build folder of the project you are trying to compile.

Comment: @VVV but there's no such file there. There are only three files there: main.cpp, Test.pro, Test.pro.user. that's it

Comment: That's a project folder. Qt Creator usually creates a build folder outside the project one. It should look something like `../build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_GCC_64bit-Debug`. Or you can look it up in the Qt Creator by selecting 'Projects' mode on the left.

Comment: @VVV I've found that file. Should I paste the whole content here (it's pretty big) or a certain part?

Comment: You may post it on pastebin or whatever.

The thing is that there is `File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Applications/Xcode` part in your compilers output. So, knowing that Qt tools don't really like spaces in the paths, and you've got one in `/Applications/Xcode 6.app/...`, my guess is that qmake had made some errors in the generated makefile. So if my quess is right then there's got to be some wrong path in the makefile, something like `/Applications/Xcode`.

Comment: @VVV I'm sorry, I need to confess that I don't quite understand what you're explaining, I've posted a part of Makefile in my question, I hope it can help you to diagnose the problem

Comment: @VVV I've also posted the whole file to http://pastebin.com/MhH7ggw9

Comment: There really is a problem with CXXFLAGS, CFLAGS and LFLAGS variables. So my advice would be to install the OSX SDK in on some space free path.

Comment: @VVV this is exactly what I did. I copied sdk folder into Documents folder and changed path inside .bash_profile file as you said but it changed nothing. the compilation output didn't change, I mean it still printed /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk path inside the output despite I expected it to be /Documents/MacOSX10.9.sdk

Comment: Run qmake again (Build->Run qmake in Qt Creator). Or close Qt Creator, delete a *.pro.user file in the project folder, delete the build folder, open the project in Qt Creator to completely reconfigure the build options.

Comment: @VVV unfortunately nothing has changed, it still produces the same output

Comment: My bad, Qt creator wouldn't recognize the path from .bash_profile if not started form the terminal. Try to start it from the terminal, like `open /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app` and reconfigure the build settings as said above. Sorry, can't test what I'm saying because I don't have a Mac here.

Comment: @VVV now it says make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the modern Mac OS way of storing environment variables (they used to be in ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist but ain't no more), though it is possible to override them in the Qt Creator's project settings pane. So you can start the Qt Creator a usual way from the finder, and change the OSX SDK root path there. Then run qmake and rebuild. If it works, then just find a way to modify the SDK root env. variable. If it doesn't then I don't know what else to try. May try to run `qmake` and `make` in the terminal in your project folder…

Comment: @VVV thank you very much for your help, buddy. I really appreciate it. I'll try to do what you said